# How to support marshalling and unmarshalling in Akka HTTP with JSON Spray for HashMap fields?

Tags: scala, akka-http, spray-json

I have the following case classes:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.HashMap
final case class GuiApplication(testSuites: TestSuites)
final case class GuiApplications(var applications: HashMap[Id, GuiApplication])
final case class Id(val id: Long)
final case class TestSuite()
final case class TestSuites(var testSuites: HashMap[Id, TestSuite])
```

The marshalling defines:

```
implicit val applicationsMapFormat = jsonFormat0(HashMap[Id, GuiApplication])
implicit val testsuitesMapFormat = jsonFormat0(HashMap[Id, TestSuite])
implicit val idFormat = jsonFormat1(Id)
implicit val testSuiteFormat = jsonFormat0(TestSuite)
implicit val testSuitesFormat = jsonFormat1(TestSuites)
implicit val applicationFormat = jsonFormat1(GuiApplication)
implicit val applicationsFormat = jsonFormat1(GuiApplications)
```

But I still get these compile errors:

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Seq[(Id, GuiApplication)] => scala.collection.immutable.HashMap[Id,GuiApplication]
[error]  required: () => ?
[error]  Note: implicit value applicationsMapFormat is not applicable here because it comes after the application point and it lacks an explicit result type
[error]   implicit val applicationsMapFormat = jsonFormat0(HashMap[Id, GuiApplication])
[error]                                                           ^
```

If I remove the first two implicits I get other compile errors.
How can I define implicit JSON formats for map types in Scala?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to write your custom `RootJsonFormat[scala.collection.immutable.HashMap[Id,GuiApplication]]` and add it to the scope of your routes:

```
implicit val hashMapFormat: RootJsonFormat[scala.collection.immutable.HashMap[Id,GuiApplication]] = new RootJsonFormat[scala.collection.immutable.HashMap[Id,GuiApplication]] {
  override def write(obj: scala.collection.immutable.HashMap[Long, String]): JsValue = ???
  override def read(json: JsValue): scala.collection.immutable.HashMap[Id,GuiApplication]  = ???
}
```

Comment: Does this mean that there is no default format for Scala maps or does Spray not know how to combine existing implicit formats to a new one?

Comment: @Baradé No, imho, spray combines known formats, the thing is it doesn't support `HashMap` out of box. One way is to change signature of your classes to use `Map[K, V]`. The other is to provide spray with explicit formatter for `HashMap`.

Comment: thx, I have changed the type to Map now since there is no point in specifying HashMap but your answer is valid for this particular question.